# JEasyUI makes the page to run twice

Tags: jquery

Here is my code. When I execute this, alert runs twice. Any help on this.

Is there any problem with my code or jeasyui framework had a problem?

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Border Layout - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jui/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="easyui-layout">
    <div region="north" border="false" style="height:60px;background:#B3DFDA;">north region</div>
    <div region="west" split="true" title="West" style="width:150px;padding:10px;">west content</div>
    <div region="east" split="true" title="East" style="width:100px;padding:10px;">east region</div>
    <div region="south" border="false" style="height:50px;background:#A9FACD;padding:10px;">south region</div>
    <div region="center" title="Main Title">

        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $().ready(function(){
                alert("hi4a11. I am running twice");
            });
        </script>
        testing
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone out there to help me???????????????

Comment: No one is there in stackoverflow to solve this huhhhhh. I am so sad

Answer (score 1):

I wonder, why do you put the ready function inside `div region="center"`?
That's where the problem is coming from.
The code runs twice, because it has been loaded when DOM ready and when layout ready.

Just move your ready script function to head section and your problem should be solved.